# Unsubscribe event in reactive extension, Execute a continuasoly

Tags: c#, system.reactive

```
public IDisposable subscription;     

 public ProcessData(DeviceModel model, string name = "") : base(model, name)
            {
                BaseAddress = _model.Process.oxyVal.regAddr;
CurrentSampleRate=1000;
                    subscription =  Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(CurrentSampleRate)).Subscribe(async t => await Refresh());

            }


public async Task Refresh()
    {
        Status = "Fetching from device...";
        if ((_model == null) || !_model.IsSerialPortOpen || busy)
        {
            StatusTrans = "Device not connected.";
            return;
        }
        busy = true;
        try
        {
            await ReadFromDevice().ConfigureAwait(false);
            StatusTrans = "Completed.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StatusTrans = ex.Message;
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        busy = false;
    }


 protected override async Task ReadFromDevice()
        {
            var SampleRate_var = await _model.Measurement.sampleRate.sampleRate.GetValue();
            CurrentSampleRate = SampleRate_var * 1000;
            /*****other code********/
        }
  public void ChangeSampleRate()
        {
            subscription?.Dispose();
            Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(CurrentSampleRate)).Subscribe(async t => await Refresh());
        }
```

I have been trying to fetching details from device.On the start,i'll subscribe a event 1 sec,in the it try to read from device(**`ReadFromDevice`**) and i'll change get the `CurrentSampleRate`,Onproperty change,that time I'll dispose 1sec subscribe event and i will  subscribe new event with current sample rate.But problem is `ReadFromDevice` happens at every 1 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var CurrentSampleRate = 30;
Observable
    .Generate(0, x => true, x => x + 1, x => x, x => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(CurrentSampleRate))
    .Subscribe(x =>
    {
        if (x == 50)
        {
            CurrentSampleRate = 1000;
        }
        Console.Write(".");
    });
```

It's a little nasty in that you're changing some external state to make the observable's interval change - so you may need to use `Interlocked.Exchange` to make the update safe.